# Backspace in access form deletes all records

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I have an access form with a textbox that is linked to a database table field, when I do "Ctrl-A and backspace" in the text box, it prompts me with "You are about to delete 124 records". How can I prevent that from happening?

I have tried the code below, but I get the same results, only difference is that the text is not highlighted.

`Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyA And Shift = acCtrlMask Then 'Catch Ctrl+A
        KeyCode = 0 'Suppress keypress 
    End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED** Just had to put "no" for allow deltions on the form properties.